# How to execute a file as program?

Tags: 64-bit, 13.04

I can't execute it as program in Ubuntu 13.04

i tried properties and then permissions then *Execute a file as program* and when i open it 
it opens by *gpedit*

i also tried `chmod +x filename.sh` and did not work

and help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `./filename.sh`  If that doesn't work, post the code error so I can more clearly see what the problem is.  Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried it and it gave me nothing as the `chmod +x filename.sh`

Comment: Just to clarify, typing ./filename.sh did absolutely nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and find a checkbox "use this file as a executable"